# Read multiple images using glob (Python) and save them in csv

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

Trying to read several images from a local folder and save them to csv using numpy.savetxt. Using following code

```
filelist = glob.glob('Filepath/*.png')
x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist])
print(x.shape)
np.savetxt('csvfile.csv', x,fmt='%s')
```

Want this code to save one image as one row in the csv in one column.
But this is storing array in 2 columns and not seperating the array to new line.
As in the image second array is stored just after the first one and not to the new row.

[252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 
 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252] [252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252 252...

Comment: Because `csv` is text format, it would be more useful if you post it as text content. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @user202729 i that ok?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try with glob.glob, what should help

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import cv2
import csv
```

Libraries ⬆️; You know what⬇️

```
image_list = []

for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\your path to\file*.png'):    # '*' will count files each by one
    
    #Read
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    flattened = img.flatten() 
    print(flattened) # recommend to avoid duplicates, see files and so on.

    #Save
    with open('output2.csv', 'ab') as f: #ab is set 
            np.savetxt(f, flattened, delimiter=",")
```

Cheers